# IIS can't find JavaScript and CSS files

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, iis, configuration

I've been working on this for a while and was wondering if anyone has run into the issue of error 404 on IIS. More specifically, when I type in `http://localhost/test/test.aspx`, the page runs, but the referenced files (JS and CSS) are not being used.

Does anyone have an idea on what this could be? keep in mind that I'm new to IIS (6.0).

Thanks!

Comment: Are your images relative to the folder or relative to the root? You might want to show the location of your images folder and an example or two of how you try to reference them in your code.

Comment: Make use of Firebug firefox plugin to check which urls are being requested from the browser for your JS/CSS.

Comment: could you post your code referencing the javascript & css files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, the path you are using to link in your style sheet and javascript files is incorrect.  Are you using "~" to link in?  Try using an absolute path to the files first.  Also does this happen in firefox as well as IE?

Comment: do you know the reason why it doesn't actually work by shorthand?

Comment: Yes.  In order for the ~ (tilda) to be evaluated, it must be a server control.  If you want to use tilda you would have to add the runat="server" to the script tag.  Only ASP.NET knows what the ~ (tilda) is.

Answer (score 0):

Are all your needed files present in your VS project explorer? If not they won't be included when you publish your project. Just copying them to your project's folder isn't good enough you have to include them in your project as well.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set compilation debug="false" in your web.config to use Jquery & css bundling regardless if .NET is running 4.0 or 4.5.

compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0"